# How to write a SQL query that uses value returned from a subquery

Tags: mysql

I’m trying to write a query so I can notify patients that need to reply to their doctor.

I first check that the patient has sent an appointment request message to the doctor.

I then check that the doctor has sent at least one message to that patient (patients always initiate a conversation, so the doctor’s message would be a reply to the patient).

I need to check that the patient hasn’t replied to the doctor yet - i.e. check that the patient has not sent a message where created_at > created_at on the doctor’s reply, but can’t figure out how to do this

```
   select messages.id from messages
   inner join patients on messages.patient_id = patients.id
   inner join doctors on messages.doctor_id = doctors.id
   where
   ( SELECT COUNT(*) from messages 
     WHERE patient_id = patients.id 
     and doctor_id = doctors.id 
     and `from` = 'patient' 
     and content LIKE 'Appointment Request:%' ) > 0
   and 
   ( SELECT COUNT(*) from messages 
     WHERE patient_id = patients.id 
     and doctor_id = doctors.id 
     and `from` = 'doctor') > 0
   and patients.created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
   group by messages.patient_id;
```

Is there a better/more efficient way to structure this query to get messages from patients who haven't replied?

I tried adding in a third subquery to check for no replies from the patient - i.e. no message with a created_at > created_at of the doctor's most recent message to the patient, but the query wouldn't run/kept timing out:

```
and
( 
  SELECT COUNT(*) from messages WHERE patient_id = patients.id and doctor_id = doctors.id and `from` = 'patient'
  HAVING messages.created_at > (SELECT max(created_at) WHERE patient_id = patients.id and doctor_id = doctors.id and `from` = 'doctor')
) = 0
```

Comment: What if the "Appointment Request" was one year ago and already took place. Now the same doctor and patient have an "conversation" regarding something else. How do you you know it's not about the appointment?

Comment: ```SELECT COUNT(*) .. WHERE {condition} ..``` === ```SELECT SUM({condition}) .. WHERE ..```

Comment: @PaulSpiegel That's why I've included `patients.created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY`, to only get messages from/for patients that signed up recently

Comment: So this is about new patients. If old patients don't send an answer, you don't care. Correct? And is it possible for a new patient to send two appointments in that week? Maybe one to Dr. X and one to Dr. Y? What do you want to show anyway? The patients data (name etc.)? The doctor's data (name, ...)? The appointment message? The doctor's answer message? Both?

Comment: Can it happen that the user sends an appointment message, the dooctor answers, then the patient answers and then the doctor answers again? Do you want to show this, as the last message was sent by the doctor without a reply from the patient? Or don't you want to show it, because the patient already replied to the doctor's initial message?

Comment: Can there be a message between patient and doctor before the appointment request? Can there be a message between patient and doctor without any appointment request?

Comment: Many, many questions. You see from our questions that it is vital that you get the rules what to select straight. Don't even try to write the query, before you know what you want to select exactly and how the query result shall look like. And when asking for help, state those rules precisely, so there can be no doubt as to what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  p.id as patient_id, 
  d.id as doctor_id
from patients p
join messages m on m.patient_id = p.id
join doctors d on d.id = m.doctor_id
where p.created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
  and m.content LIKE 'Appointment Request:%'
  and (
    select mlast.from
    from messages mlast
    where mlast.patient_id = m.patient_id
      and malst.doctor_id  = m.doctor_id
    order by mlast.created_at desc
    limit 1
  ) = 'doctor'
group by p.id, d.id
```

Read it like this: Get messages with `content LIKE 'Appointment Request:%'` but only from patients with `created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY`. Now look at the last message between that doctor and patient (last condition with subquery) - It must be from the doctor. You can also use `<> 'patient'` if that does matter.

GROUP BY is for the case if there are multiple matching messages.

Add what ever columns you need from the `patients` and the `doctors` tables in the `SELECT` clause.